# new row for relation "venues" violates check constraint "enforce_srid_latlon"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgis

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a new venue that is location aware.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  new row for relation "venues" violates check constraint "enforce_srid_latlon"
```

This is the method I follow to recreate the error.

```
v = Venue.create(:latlon => "POINT (43.245332 -85.4352332)")
v.save
```

I did notice that in my migrations, I did not set the :geographic => true property for t.point :latlon. Could that be what's causing my problems? If so, how do I set that flag to true on a column that already contains data?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, using FactoryGirl.create

Comment: aha. It turns out my spatial_ref_sys tables is getting cleared out, which is why I get this error in testing, but not in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to set your SRID is to prefix the WKT into EWKT (extended well-known text):

```
v = Venue.create(:latlon => "SRID=4326;POINT (43.245332 -85.4352332)")
```

I'm using [SRID=4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/), since it looks like you have WGS84 latitude/longitude coordinates, which is typical.

Answer (score 3):

As the (Postgres) error message tells you, the new row would violate the check constraint `enforce_srid_latlon`.

Look at the definition of the check constraint and you will have your answer.
In **psql** you can use:

```
\d venues
```

Or you can use this **SQL query** from any client:

```
SELECT r.conname, pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
WHERE  r.conrelid = 'venues'::regclass
AND    r.contype = 'c'
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Or you can use a GUI like [**pgAdmin**](http://www.pgadmin.org/).

Comment: Useful! Thanks, yes in PGadmin it would be Schemas > tables > table > constraints